# Retornar uma unica linha por codigo

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, firebird

tenho uma tabela que guarda registro de um cliente e sua vigência em operação.
a sql precisa me retornar somente a ultima vigência do cliente (a mais recente). 
nenhum codigo pode se repetir[image: imagem da tabela simples]

segue o resultado que a sql deveria me mostrar:
[image: resultado da sql]

Comment: Poderia adicionar algum código à pergunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumindo que seu campo final_vigencia sejam do tipo DATE faça:

```
SELECT codigo, MAX(final_vigencia) FROM sua_tabela GROUP BY codigo;
```

Comment: Muito bom. resolveu meu problema!